# Cakephp dropdown selected value not coming correctly in firefox when a page is refreshed

Tags: php, firefox, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I'm having error in setting up a drop down selected value returned from a controller in firefox only.. Im using cakephp 1.3.

It comes right when i first time load the pages but if i change the drop down value and refresh the page the value doesnt changed. It should be the one coming from controller.

But when i press ctrl+f5 the right value is showed up.

I guess it is something to do with the browser cache.
Im not having this problem in google chrome.

im setting the value of the dropdown with selected value using this code

```
echo $this->Form->input('to_country_code',array(
            'options'=>$countries,
            'id'=>'to_country_code',
            'label' => __('Country',true),
            //'selected'=>$selectedCountryCode
            'div' => false,
            'default'=>$selectedToCountryCode
            )
        );
```

Any answers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you should seriously consider to offer a coffee to Vins for taking the time to give you to the answer to the same problem a second time... ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316836/cakephp-dropdowns-not-showing-right-data-when-refreshing-the-page

Comment: well actually i updated my question with more code detail after Vins initial answer. But i didn't got the reply. Then i had to ask this particular firefox problem with a new thread. But got the clarification now :) n yes coffee is due for Vins from my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox will retain your form values when you refresh the page, no doubt it will reflect the changes. Its  only to help users for not to loose the input which is already entered. But if you click on the address bar and press enter then entire page will be loaded with initial values.

Its not a Cakephp issue.

Comment: Thank you Vins .. for the explanation. i really appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

This is something particular to Firefox, not CakePHP. It caches some of the form data unless you hard refresh.

Comment: is there a way around to this problem. There are many php sites and it work completely fine on firefox .